# Symfony REST pagination

Tags: rest, symfony, pagination

I have the following problem, I would like to do pagination, but without using FosRestBundle, in pure symfony. The problem is that pagination theoretically works, but practically json returns only the current page, limit and the number of pages without data. My code:

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
$limit = $request->get('limit', 2);
$page = $request->get('page', 1);
$offset = ($page -1) *$limit;

$nameRepository = $doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Name');
$names = $nameRepository->findBy([], [], $limit, $offset);
$namesCount = $nameRepository->count();

$pageCount = (int)ceil($namesCount / $limit);
$collection = new CollectionRepresentation($names);
$paginated = new PaginatedRepresentation(
   $collection,
   'user_list',
   [],
   $page,
   $limit,
   $pageCount
);

$content = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($paginated, 'json');
return new JsonResponse($content,200);
```

Without serialization, he does not return anything to me, and I can not figure out where the problem is. With serialization, he returns to me:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 2,
    "pages": 2
}
```

I suspect it's a question of returning data, but I can not figure out what the problem is :(

Comment: [Using limit and offset in doctrine query builder for manual pagination](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/0s5l/using-limit-and-offset-in-doctrine-query-builder-for-manual-pagination). Start from `StudentService:get`.

Comment: Doctrine has a helper class for pagination see the docs at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/pagination.html might be usefull.

Comment: can you add some more relevant code from `PaginatedRepresentation` and probbly `CollectionRepresentation`.